# Limiting the framerate of HTML <video> element

Tags: canvas, html5-video

Would it be possible, through JS or otherwise, to limit the FPS of a `<video>` element?  I've gotten as far as determining that it probably needs to be drawn to a `<canvas>`, but then how would one limit the frames drawn per second on that `<canvas>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple enough. The best way to do any kind of video/canvas effects is to start with `requestAnimationFrame`, and then on each cycle, you can choose whether to draw the frame or to skip it. Assuming 2D canvas for maximum compatibility, like so:

```
var MAX_FRAME_RATE = 5, // frames per second
    FRAME_DIFF = 1000 / MAX_FRAME_RATE,
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    video = document.getElementById('video'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    lastDraw = 0;

function render() {
    var now = Date.now(),
        diff = now - lastDraw;

    if (diff >= FRAME_DIFF) {
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        lastDraw = now;
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

render();
```

Comment: +1 tip: rAF already provides a (hi-res) time stamp for the callback (ie. `function render(now) { var diff = now - lastDraw; ...}`); no need to use Date.now(). And of course, invoke first call with `render(0);` A whopping one line less code but also more accurate times which can potentially give a slightly smoother experience if non-alignable frame rates are used.

Comment: Good call @Epistemex. +1 for you.

Comment: +1 Perfect. I thought it had something to do with `requestAnimationFrame` as I'd seen that around before, thanks for the full implementation.